# Best current synoptic treatment of Plato & Parmenides

Tags: plato, parmenides

I've come to realise the seminal importance of Parmenides for Western philosophy. But not being a classics scholar, or being able to read ancient Greek, much of the literature about Parmenides and Plato's commentaries on the same is impenetrable. It contains commentaries on commentaries, passages in Greek often presented without translation, and in general is meaningful only to specialized scholars deeply grounded in Classical studies (e.g. Plato & Parmenides by Cornford, available at no cost online.)

So can anyone recommend a current book which does a reasonable job of digesting and presenting this subject? There are quite a few titles available in online bookstores but it would help if knowledgeable readers were to recommend the best of them.

Comment: This looks promising, as it's a current edition and is said to be suitable for non-scholars 
 https://www.amazon.com.au/dp/1930972202

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I've answered my own question! I discovered a small publishing house called Parmenides Publishing, and through that, two books by Arnold Hermann, an independent scholar - just the books I was looking for.